# Retrieve the correct found objective values via the C-API

Tags: z3

I am trying to find the boundary values of the variables in a formula. To do this I feed the formula to Z3 (version 4.8.9 - 64 bit on Ubuntu 22.04) and then use the objective criteria to either minimize or maximize the variables. By looking at the found objectives I get the result I am interested in. To embed this in my code, I need to do the same thing but then via the C-API but I can't seem to find the correct way to do this.

---

I'll start with an example in SMT2Lib:
For instance, I have the following formula `x == 3 || (x > y) && (y == 10)`. In SMT2Lib this would be:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)

(assert (or (= x 3) (and (> x y) (= y 10))))
```

To prevent having to deal with infinity I add the following assertions to limit the domains to (-1000,1000):

```
(assert (and (> x (- 1000)) (< x 1000)))
(assert (and (> y (- 1000)) (< y 1000)))
```

I want to minimize x and y (basically all variables) using the standard lexicographical ordering:

```
(minimize x)
(minimize y)
```

Checking satisfiability and retrieving the model yields the following result:

```
(check-sat)
sat
(get-model)
(model 
  (define-fun y () Int
    2)
  (define-fun x () Int
    3)
)
```

Please note that the returned model does not contain the minimal value for `y` for this example, but the objectives do always seem to return the correct values:

```
(get-objectives)
(objectives
 (x 3)
 (y (- 999))
)
```

The question now is, how can I actually get the found objectives via the C-API? The C-API has a method to retrieve the objectives (`Z3_optimize_get_objectives`) but this only seems to return the actual objectives (in this case `(- x)` and `(- y)`) and not the found values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found out that the latest version of Z3 does give a truly minimized model with the default `get-model` command. So it seems that there might be no need to look at the objectives at all. Was there indeed a change in some more recent Z3 release that has caused this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really use `lower`/`upper` etc., but directly evaluate the values in the model you obtained. Here's the standard way of solving this problem, using C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "z3++.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    z3::context ctx;
    z3::expr x = ctx.int_const("x");
    z3::expr y = ctx.int_const("y");

    z3::optimize opt(ctx);

    opt.add((x == 3) || ((x > y) && (x == 10)));
    opt.add((x > -1000) && (x < 1000));
    opt.add((y > -1000) && (y < 1000));

    opt.maximize(x);
    opt.minimize(y);

    z3::check_result res = opt.check();

    if (res == z3::sat) {
        std::cout << x << ": " << opt.get_model().eval(x) << endl;
        std::cout << y << ": " << opt.get_model().eval(y) << endl;
    } else {
       cout << "Result isn't sat: " << res << endl;
       return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming the above is in `a.cpp`, compile it like this:

```
c++ a.cpp   -o a -lz3
```

Running it yields:

```
x: 10
y: (- 999)
```

which I believe is the solution you're looking for.

Note that you have to be careful if any of your objectives can become `oo` or `-oo`: If this is the case, then the values you'll get from `opt.get_model().eval` cannot be trusted. They're only valid if the assignment produces finite values to the variables in the model.

EDIT: As Patrick Trentin notes in the comments, you also have to be careful if your objective-values are not the same as model-variables. (Objectives are in general functions of model-variables.) In your case, there's a one-to-one correspondence; so you needn't worry so long as you know the optimal values are finite. But you could be led astray if the objective values become unbounded while the model variables remain finite, which wouldn't be trustable. (This can happen, for instance, if your objective value is independent of some of the variables you're querying, for instance.) Thanks to Patrick for point out this intricate detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, this is what I am looking for. The problem I ran into was that the version of Z3 I was using, 4.8.6, apparently does not always give back the minimized model as first solution. The latest version 4.12.6 however, does seem to do so.

Comment: Might be a bug in 4.8.6, which is 5 years old by now. I wouldn’t worry about it unless you see similar behavior in the latest versions.

Comment: The difference between `model_eval()` and `lower/upper` is that the former is a specific finite value, and the latter can be symbolic value. This is important when the objective function can be unbounded, as you noted, or when it can be infinitesimally close to a value (i.e. `k + epsilon`). Hence, I would argue that when one is interested in the value of the objective function, they should use the objective function itself or the lower/upper bounds. I don't know about `z3`, but `OptiMathSAT` does provide bindings to access these values (and it allows to choose the model to use in MA setting).

Comment: My past experience was that z3 does not necessarily pick models that are 'close' to the optimal value of objective functions that tend to infinite or epsilon and, in fact, it tends to pick models whose values are quite far from that. Hence, I would make the opposite recommendation and instead say that one should never use model values as-is unless  they are interested in a specific solution. Again, this  might have changed  and there might exist options to control that, same as with OptiMathSAT.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I think in this case it is OK; since objective functions are essentially the same as the model values themselves. I'd agree with your observation if that wasn't the case, i.e., if objectives were a function of the model-variables. In the simple case we have here where objectives are identical to model-variables, I think we're safe so long as we know the objective values are finite themselves.

Comment: Agreed! My comments were for the more general case.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I added an extra-paragraph to clarify this intricate case. Thanks for the help. Feel free to edit!

Answer (score 0):

The following C++ example might help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "z3++.h"

//  https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp

#define LOG_Z3_CALLS

#ifdef LOG_Z3_CALLS
#define LOG_MSG(msg) Z3_append_log(msg)
#else
#define LOG_MSG(msg) ((void)0)
#endif

using namespace z3;


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Z3 C++ API example\n";

    context ctx;
    expr x = ctx.int_const("x");
    expr y = ctx.int_const("y");

    optimize opt(ctx);
    params p(ctx);
    p.set("priority", ctx.str_symbol("pareto"));
    opt.set(p);

    opt.add((x == 3) || ((x > y) && (x == 10)));

    opt.add((x > -1000) && (x < 1000));
    opt.add((y > -1000) && (y < 1000));

    int64_t prevx = 0;
    int64_t prevy = 0;
    int unchanged = 0;
    int itera = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (sat == opt.check()) {          
            model m = opt.get_model();
            int64_t ivx = m.eval(x).as_int64();
            int64_t ivy = m.eval(y).as_int64();

            if ((ivx == prevx) && (ivy == prevy)) { 
                unchanged++;
            } else {
                prevx = ivx;
                prevy = ivy;
                unchanged = 0;
            }
            std::cout << x << ": " << ivx << " " 
                      << y << ": " << ivy << "\n";

            if (unchanged > 10) {
                std::cout << "No more change?\n";
                break;
            }
            else if (++itera > 20) {
                std::cout << "Too many iterations\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This model oscillates between a small number of solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
In your example you ask for the lower limits of both variables. I think that this will return -999 for both. But asserting that both x and y are -999 will result in a invalid model of the formula. So, I'm looking for a solution were Z3 gives the correct model values for the given minimization or maximization criteria. 
But, as I noticed, it might just be that later versions of Z3 actually do give the models I am interested in via the normal `get-model` command.

Comment: Use of `upper`/`lower` here is misleading, you shouldn't really mess with handles unless you are building a custom optimizer yourself, which isn't what the OP is asking for.  Getting a model, and calling `eval` on it is the best practice for this sort of a problem.

Comment: The original question asks for a lexicographic optimization, not the pareto fronts, which is quite a different concept.